# How to set font family in iText 5?

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext, font-family

I can't figure out how to simply set a font family on an existing pdf field with iText 5. I've found the official documentation on this issue to be pretty lacking.

Here is how I'm trying to call this font (I just want Helvetica, which comes w/ the FontFactory library):

`Font Helvetica = FontFactory.getFont("Helvetica");
form.setFieldProperty("Text Field 1", "textfont", "Helvetica", null);`

When I run the above code, I get the console error message:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.setFieldProperty(AcroFields.java:1033)
    at com.eb.anico.web.pdf.manipulatePdf(pdf.java:87)
    at com.eb.anico.web.pdf.main(pdf.java:55)`

I'm able to do other things like make a field multi-line, center the field, and change font color. But changing font family still wont work. Here's my full code:

```
package com.pathtopackage;

import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;


import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font.FontFamily;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FontSelector;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.GrayColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PushbuttonField;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextField;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class pdf  {



public static final String SRC = "src/resources/ads-horizontal-box-defined-size-single-line.pdf";
   public static final String DEST = "src/resources/ads-horizontal-box-defined-size-single-line-STYLED-TXTSIZEAUTOACROBAT-7.pdf";


   public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
       File file = new File(DEST);
       file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
       new pdf().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
   }

   public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
       PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
       AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
       Item item = form.getFieldItem("Text Field 1");


       form.setFieldProperty("Text Field 1", "fflags", PdfFormField.FF_MULTILINE, null); //convert field to multiline
       item.getMerged(0).put(PdfName.Q, new PdfNumber(PdfFormField.Q_CENTER)); //center form field



       Font Helvetica = FontFactory.getFont("Helvetica");
       form.setFieldProperty("Text Field 1", "textfont", "Helvetica", null);
       form.setFieldProperty("Text Field 1", "textcolor", new BaseColor(0, 93, 171), null);
       form.setFieldProperty("Text Field 1", "textsize", new Float(16), null); //change field font size to 16



       PdfDictionary widget = item.getWidget(0);
       PdfArray rect = widget.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
       rect.set(2, new PdfNumber(rect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue()));
       String value = "Kyle Vassella";
       form.setField("Text Field 1", value);
       stamper.setFormFlattening(true); //flatten pdf
       stamper.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All of this is neatly explained in ´iText in action´ chapter 8.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-8

One way of going about this, is to use the individual form objects themselves, rather than the form as a whole.

```
PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, rect, "Buttons");
button.setBackgroundColor(new GrayColor(0.75f));
button.setBorderColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
button.setBorderWidth(1);
button.setBorderStyle(PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED);
button.setTextColor(GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);
button.setFontSize(12);
```

Check out the API for iText5 as well, so that you have a clear idea of what the parameters for each method are.

http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText5/5.5.11/